# "Could not find composer.json file" error in CraftCMS 3

Tags: craft3, composer

I recently updated my CraftCMS 3 with the help of Composer.

When I try to install a plugin with the plugin store, I get an error saying that Craft couldn't find my composer.json file. He proposes me to define the  CRAFT_COMPOSER_PATH in index.php. But, when I do, I still get the same error.

My composer.json is the root of craft folder. I seriously don't know how to solve my problem.

Here's a screenshot (sorry I use Craft in french):

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: in root plugin folder has file composer.json?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I don't have a Plugin folder at the root because Craft 3.3.15 doesn't have a plugin folder.

Comment: /vendor/pluginName/composer.json

Comment: I see what you mean. But I can't access that if the plugin I want is not installed. The plugin store won't install the plugin I want because it can't find my root composer.json.

Comment: follow this tutorial: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/php-constants.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8396)

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your index.php file and add the composer path line.
E.g. my composer.json file is placed in the root folder and I defined the below path inside my index.php:

```
    <?php
 
//Project root path
$root = dirname(__DIR__);
 
 
// Load and run Craft
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', $root.'/craft');
define('CRAFT_COMPOSER_PATH', $root.'/composer.json'); **<=== this line**
require_once $root.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require $root.'/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
$app->run();
```